# Not able to modify class composite data members

Tags: c++, class, oop, member, member-functions

I have `3` classes in my program that interact with each other and contain each other's instances:

```
class Inventory 
{
public:
   // Increment Data Members
   void incrementHerbs() { herbs++; }
   void incrementHealth() { health++; }
   void incrementGold() { gold++; }

   // Getters
   int getHerbs() { return herbs; }
   int getHealth() { return health; }
   int getGold() { return gold; }

private:
   int herbs = 0;
   int health = 3;
   int gold = 0;
};

class Player 
{
public:
   void setRow(int row) { this->rowCoordinate = row; }
   void setCol(int col) { this->colCoordinate = col; }
   int getRow() { return rowCoordinate; }
   int getCol() { return colCoordinate; }
   Inventory getBag() { return Bag; }

private:
   int rowCoordinate;
   int colCoordinate;
   Inventory Bag;
};

class Board
{
public:
   int getNumRows() { return numRows; }
   int getNumCols() { return numCols; }
   Player getPlayer() { return User; }

private:
   int numRows;
   int numCols;
   char** maze;
   Player User;
};
```

I am only instantiating a `Board` object in the `main` function. At a point in my program, I want to be able to increment the `herb` count in the inventory class through that object.

I have tried doing:

```
Board board;
board.getPlayer().getBag().incrementHerbs();
```

This call compiles without any errors but when I print out the `herb` count afterwards, the `herb` count is still the same.

It did not increment. What can be going wrong and what can I do?

Comment: Thats because you return the bag by value which means when you call incremenetHerbs you are modifying a *copy* of your player's Bag not their actual bag. You should use references (if you dont know about them, now is a great time to!)

Comment: Your `Board` class doesn't extend `Inventory` nor does it contain an `Inventory` member. How could it possibly know if some unrelated instance of `Inventory` changed its `herb` count?

Answer (score 3):

> What can be going wrong and what can I do?

In your `Player` class, your `getBag()` function returns a copy of `Inventory` (i.e. member `Bag`).

```
Inventory getBag() { return Bag; }
//^^^^^^----> is copy!
```

You need to return the reference in order to modify it

```
Inventory& getBag() { return Bag; }
//^^^^^^^^
```

The same issue with the `Board`'s function `getPlayer()`

```
Player getPlayer() { return User; }
//^^^^----> is copy!
```

you need

```
Player& getPlayer() { return User; }
//^^^^^^
```

And here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jTrhca).